# Replicate SQL Server data to Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have few tables from multiple SQL Server databases which I want to replicate into SF (for analytics purposes). I'm not ready to purchase any external tools.

Is there a way to accomplish without any tools?

Answer (score 4):

I did this last year and also did not want to spend much money.

I did the following:

1. Create BCP script outputs to JSON files
2. Using AWS CLI or if you want to spend $59 dollars use TnT Drive and put the
   JSON files created from the BCP export into S3
3. Add a stage in Snowflake pointing to your S3 bucket
4. Create External Table definitions in Snowflake to your S3 files
5. Query the data in Snowflake

For my situation, I found that ODBC and Python were slower than BCP exported files with Snowflake External Tables.

`bcp "select (select * for json path, without_array_wrapper) from Product" queryout .products.json  -c -S "SQLSERVER" -d ProductCatalog -T`

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to spend any money then you probably have 3 categories of option:

1. Use Snowflake's COPY INTO functionality. This will require you to export your data into flat files and upload them into a stage before you can run the COPY INTO
2. Code your own solution using one of the Snowflake supported interfaces:

   - ODBC, JDBC, Python, .NET and a few others
3. Use a free ETL tool. For example, Talend has a free version which may support Snowflake as a target

I guess the best solution for you depends on your existing skillset and/or how much time you are prepared to spend learning new technology

Comment: Thanks @NickW, I would try #2. Talend is also a good though.